# Bread maker - is this even a collapse or did it not get started?

Tags: bread

I have used the machine successfully several times but something went very wrong today. My machine is an Oster. The top surface is powdery and underneath it is as hard as a rock. Almost looks like power was lost part way through. We did hear it operating for quite a while. What went wrong?

[image]

Comment: That looks like the flour didn't get mixed in, so it never really started.  Did you use sufficient liquid for the amount of flour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like a measurement error.  Not nearly enough liquid.